# Label each row of an HTML table numerically (PHP + MYSQL)

Tags: php, html, html-table, row

All I want is for the first column of each row in my table to display the number of the current row. For example, please see the following table.

```
Column Header 1    Column Header 2
1                     some data
2                     more data
3                     some more data
4                     even more data
```

I am familiar with JavaScript (I will most likely understand any JS script posted), CSS, and HTML. I am curious as to whether or not I will have to write a JS function to do this, or if I can somehow just create a variable and increase its index by ' 1 ' each time.

I look forward to your responses!

Comment: generally if you are loading data it will come from a server-side preprocessing language like PHP, unless you are planning to retrive the data asynchronously. What environment are you working in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using PHP, try to get an array of strings for data you want to output:

```
$data = array('here', 'is', 'some', 'data');

// Avoid printing table if there is no data
if (count($data) > 0) {
    echo '<table><tr><td>Column Header 1</td><td>Column Header 2</td></tr>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        echo '<tr><td>', $i + 1, '</td><td>', $data[$i], '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Hit the nail on the head! Perfect!

Comment: edit: if you're reading in data, it's good to make sure that it's there to avoid printing a table without rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS autonumbering

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters

This is the client side solution. Use it if you can not do it on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a table, or could you use an [ol](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-OL)?

```
<ol>
    <li>some data</li>
    <li>more data</li>
    <li>some more data</li>
    <li>even more data</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It will be a MYSQL table created using PHP.

Comment: Ah, I would go with kisp's approach then. If that doesn't work, either generate the numbering in the PHP, or client-side with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on kisp's approach of CSS numbering, I created [a prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/uKxxR/) which appears to do almost what you are looking for. The numbering isn't in a separate collumn, it's in the "before" pseudo-element.